# Replace the same placeholder + different placeholder with same/different values in a string

Tags: php, replace

I don't figure out how this can work. First, I have got a template which contains placeholders. Here's a part of the template.

```
<a>{nlink}</a>
<a>{nlink}</a>
<a>{nlink}</a>
<a>{nlink}</a>
<a>{nlink}</a>
<a>{nlink}</a>
<a>{nlink}</a>

<ul>
    <a href='#'>{ptitle}</a>
    <a href='#'>{nlink_cat}</a>
    <a href='#'>{cat_sel}</a>
    <br style='clear:both;' />
</ul>
```

My problem is that I want to replace the {nlink} placeholders with values which I got from the database (categories). The other placeholders will be replaced with datas from the db, too. Does anyone have an idea how this can work? I only know how to replace single placeholders while using strtr().

regards

Comment: there are  many very good exiting template engines

Comment: The problem is I created the template with html and css by my own. I want to build a CMS and I wanted to link the template to the CMS so I thought I have to make this template engine by myself or can I simply use one and implement a template engine?

Comment: perhaps you should use an existing CMS

Comment: I really want to make my own cms. I alrady made a cms by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your tags one by one to correspond with each value in a loop over your categories from the database. [Here's an example](https://eval.in/175041):

```
$categories = array(
  'Apples',
  'Oranges',
  'Bananas',
  'Carrots',
  'Tangelos',
  'Tomatoes',
  'Raspberries'
);

foreach($categories as $category) {
    // Only replace the tag once (each time it repeats, the previous tag is gone
    // so we move on to the next one
    $html = preg_replace('/{nlink}/', $category, $html, 1);
}

echo $html;
```

Output:

```
<a>Apples</a>
<a>Oranges</a>
<a>Bananas</a>
<a>Carrots</a>
<a>Tangelos</a>
<a>Tomatoes</a>
<a>Raspberries</a>
```

Comment: For the sake of templating systems, a better approach would be to loop through your categories and output all the HTML there and then so that your arbitrary number of `<a></a>` tags will actually correspond with the number of categories in your DB... something like `foreach($categories as $category) { echo '<a>' . $category . '</a>'; }`